# Neighborhood of a point in Topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $x \in X$ and define a topological space $(X, \tau)$ and let singleton set {$x$} $\in \tau$. Then by definition of neighborhood of a point in topology, {${x}$} will be a neighborhood of point $x$. My question is

> If set {$x$} does not contain any other point then $x$, then how does it make sense to say that this singleton set is a neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: What topology are you considering here?

Comment: It's because you are defining the singleton set to be an open set in your topology.

Comment: @monroej by definition it is true, but neighborhood of $x$ in real analysis contains some points around $x$, here there is no other point.

Comment: @B.S. let say topology $\tau$ is the whole power set.

Comment: @AbhinavSahani True... but you aren't using either the real numbers or their usual topology here.  So, the "shape" of the space can be very different!  Saying that $\{x\}$ is open can be thought of as saying that there are "no other points near $x$".

Comment: In topology a neighborhood of a point $x$ is just a set $V$ that contains an open set $U$ with $x\in U$.  But I totally see where the confusion arises!

Comment: To see a case in which this ''really'' happens: look at $X = [0,1] \cup \{2\}$ with the topology induced by $\mathbb R$. $\{2\}$ is indeed a neighborhood of the point 2 - and that doesn't look at all unreasonable, does it?

Comment: So it's a neighborhood of $x$ that does not really contain any 'neighbours' of $x$. Mathematicians are kind of peculiar, aren't they :)-.

Comment: One well-known possibility is to consider [Discrete Metric](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteMetric.html) on your non empty set $X$.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson that is quite ok. but let us consider the topology to be whole power set, there we may find neighborhoods that will have some points around $x$ and also {$x$}, then how will your sentence make sense?

Comment: The fact that there ARE open sets which include $x$ and other points doesn't change the fact that you've declared $\{x\}$ an open set.  Because $\{x\}$ is itself open, you can separate $x$ from all other points in $X$.

Comment: @monroej doesn't neighborhood have to be open?

Comment: It depends on your definition.  Some people say "open neighborhood" of $x$ to mean...well just that, an open set containing $x$.  Other people say neighborhood to mean open neighborhood.  It really just depends on your text.  Luckily, in this case, it didn't matter.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson so can we say that a isolated point $x$ is a neighborhood of that point?(talking in the sense of real analysis)

Comment: I like the definition of neighborhood that I put in my second comment.  But that's just me.

Comment: A point $x$ is isolated if and only if $\{x\}$ is open in the topology, yes.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson beat me to it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You stated that the singleton is an open set (you said {$x$} $\in \tau$). An open set is a neighbourhood of any of its own elements, by the definition of neighbourhood.

Comment: You made me doubt again: is it 'neighborhood' of 'neighbourhood'?

Comment: let's just say, I don't live in the US :).